# I am looking for music akin to this piece of music, "Vengeance of the Blood Elves". Where can I find music like this?

Tags: similar-artists, videogame-soundtrack

Where can I find instrumental music similar to this that has deep, mystical, arcane, and intriguing themes?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw1Wab6DpHg

This is from the Warcraft III official soundtrack. Where can I find music like this?

Comment: To me this seems just like classic music, with some environmental feel to it. Have you tried soundtracks from similar games or movies? Perhaps The Elder Scrolls Series or The Lord of the Ring Series?

Comment: Yes, I've looked into that. I've given Richard Wagner and Rachmaninoff a go. I adore the LOTR and Elder Scrolls soundtrack. 

Thank you kindly for your input.

Comment: I have an answer for this question and will post the answer when my situation, involving a sick family member, is over. Please don't remove this question. This is the kind of music I was talking about: < https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqNtiPwm45g >. I'll rewrite the question and improve it a lot, later; including better clarification. The question can be improved with sources.

Comment: Thanks for the input -- Jeremy Soule is a valid answer. I agree with most of Lucas Sant'anna's (user) points. Let's avoid a fight over such a mild topic like high fantasy music. I wish you the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like epic music with strings like this, I can recommend you to listen to Two Steps from Hell:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9O4_awEHh1g

Pay attention also to Immediate Music:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8J8FuNs300

Answer (score 1):

> " ... deep, mystical, arcane, and intriguing themes ... " ~ Tautological Revelations, opening poster

You can try this song, "Arcane Library":--

I present to you "Arcane Refuge" from *Wizard of Legend's* soundtrack:--

---

There are elves in these pictures:--

[image]

I present to you, "Flowing Sky," by Grzegorz Wlodarski:

I present to you, "Circle of Life," by Grzegorz Wlodarski:

---

If you simply mean songs about "dark elves," then there is this song, "Dark Elves" by Brandon Fiechter:--